# Resource sharing between two separate locks in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Suppose I am having a code something like this.

```
    object lock1 = new object();
    object lock2 = new object();

    lock (lock1)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    lock (lock2)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

Will it allow lock2 to access the shared resources that are being accessed by lock1 while it is being processed or not? If not, then is there a way to lock all the processes under the name lock1 while lock2 should not be affected by that.

Comment: It depends on the first and second `// Do something`. Without showing us the actual  `// Do something` code, it's unlikely that we will be able to offer any useful advice.

Comment: Locking is about preventing the same code from executing in parallel, not about restricting resources. If a resource is processed inside `lock2`, another thread will be able access it from `lock1`.

Comment: In addition to @WiktorZychla response, while this type of locking prevents different threads accessing a method concurrently, it importantly does not prevent re-entrancy from the same thread (since it already has acquired the lock), such as if the method used any type of recursion, or went through a series of other methods before one of those called this method again.

Comment: If you have a look at [ReaderWriterLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?view=net-7.0) class - does it seem to solve your problem?

Comment: There are special thread safe collections and types in .Net you can use. I haven't worked with threads for a long time, so google is your friend.